# Find pattern inside a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use the `re`module given by Python but I think that I missed something. What I want to do is to be able to say if a given pattern is inside a sentence, for instance :

I have my sentence "The sky is blue today"
And I want to find if the pattern `blu* tod*` is inside the sentence

I tried many things such as :

```
data = 'The sky is blue today'
pattern = 'blu*\stod*
re.match(pattern,data,re.IGNORECASE) // doesn't worked
pattern = [blu+]\s[tod+] 
re.search(pattern,data) // Match everything in my sentence, even if the pattern isn't inside
```

Can someone help me? Or maybe point me to a good tutorial about finding regex inside a sentence?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misunderstood what `*` and `+` do in regular expressions. They're not wildcards like in file globbing: they are respectively "0 or more" or "1 or more" of the *previous character*. So it's looking for something like "bluuuuuu todddddd".

The other problem is that you're using `match` and `search` interchangeably, but in fact `match` will only match from the start of the string. You need `search` here.

So your code should probably be:

```
data = 'The sky is blue today'
pattern = 'blu.+\stod.+'
re.search(pattern,data)
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to learn the difference between greedy and lazy, and how to use the dot.  I like this site:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: He was asking for a good tutorial, and a good tutorial, IMHO, would have to come in the form of a link.  I also didn't want to just feed him the answer.